# How to display/present the numbers in my listbox with a tab before the number

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to tab the items/number within my listbox.

However, I'm not sure how to do this with the below code

```
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int idx = rnd.Next(i, a);

        //swap elements
        int tmp = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[i]);

        (lstHoldValue.Items[i]) = Convert.ToInt32(lstHoldValue.Items[idx]);
        (lstHoldValue.Items[idx]) = Convert.ToInt32(tmp);
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "tab"?

Comment: such as "\t". I would like to present the numbers in my listbox with a tab before the number.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop, then, for every element, add a tab after numbers. Find the digits with Regex.

```
foreach (string i in lstHoldValue)
{
    string match = Regex.Match(i, "\d+").Value; //Any first number, can be multidigit
    string rest = i.Substring(match.Length); //Rest of String
    string result = match + "\t" + rest; //Result
    //Apply result to List
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doesnt seem to work, getting errors with lstHolevalue, does not contain a public definiton for GetEnumertaor and regax does not exist and so doesn't substring.